# Android: Download media from url

Tags: android, kotlin, download, background-process

What is the modern (2019) approach to **download media** (Images, videos, audios, etc...) from URL with *Kotlin*?

Apparently there are a lot of different mechanisms you can use in terms of background fetching:

- `Service`
- `JobService`
- `IntentService`
- `JobScheduler`
- `BroadcastReceiver`
- `AsyncTask`
- `DownloadManager`
- `PoolExecutor`s
- As well as any possible combination of these and maybe others not even listed here...

I could find at least 1 example for almost every item in the list above, however I couldn't find a "standard", "recommended" or "official" approach either from Google or the Android Dev Community.

(Not asking for a silver bullet here, just wondering what is the most or some of the most consistent and of course modern ways for such a common task)

Comment: Context: Android multimedia player app

Comment: Your context isn't really the relevant bit. When are these downloads occurring, with respect to the operation of your app? And, what is the trigger for these downloads (user interaction with UI? push message? polling a podcast service? something else?)

Comment: Downloads are triggered automatically by push messages if wlan connectivity is available otherwise user should be able to start them manually through UI interaction as well as pause/cancel them.

Answer (score 1):

[**Service**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) is the fastest - You can download as much as needed immediately. You will need to elevate it to foreground (with sticky notification) to start and/or keep it alive when your app is not in foreground.

[**JobScheduler**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) + [**JobService**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html) is less intrusive but its time of execution is managed by the system, so it's not suitable for immediate request. You can however schedule it to run periodically to check if there's something new to download.

[**DownloadManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) is a system service. Unlike other methods download does not happen within your apps process. You don't need to write any connection methods yourself then, but You're relying on unknown implementation which may vary per-device. Any problems that occur like throttling/stuck queue/cancellation are out of your control.